# Открытое меню

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Есть ну совсем простой скрипт меню-гармошки:

```
    function initMenu() {
    $('.menu ul').hide();
    $('.menu li a').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);    
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

HTML:

```
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home<span>13</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
                    <li class="current"><a href="#">Menu second</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Как сделать, чтобы если есть класс .current внутри `<li>`, то это раздел должен быть изначально раскрыт? Зарание спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените селектор:

```
$('.menu ul:not(:has(li.current))').hide();
```

- **[:not() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**
- **[:has() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)**